# React Native sharing constants and hooks between functional components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

My question is in the title: In react native, is it possible to share hooks between multiple functional components? If I would want to share functions and constants between functional components for example, I could do:

File1.tsx:

```
//outside the functional component
export const _file1function = function(){
   return "This came from file1" ;
}
export default function File1 () {
  ....
}
```

File2.tsx:

```
import * as f1 from './File1'
export default function File2 () {
...
    f1._file1function() //is valid
...
}
```

However, if I attempt to replicate similar behavior, and export constants with hooks:

```
export const [test, setTest] = React.useState(0);
export const _hookfunction = function(){
   setTest(1);
   return true;
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
```

Therefore it seems like I just need to put those constants and functions within a functional component like so:

```
export default function HookTest() {
  const [test, setTest] = React.useState(0);
   const _hookfunction = function(){
       setTest(1);
       return true;
   }
}
```

And this now looks like a normal react native app using hooks. How can I access those functions and constants from another script? Is sharing hooks between functional components and screens possible? If not, are there other ways to obtain this behavior, or does this completely go against react fundamentals?

Comment: You could write a custom hook, but do you want that every component share the same value of `test`? If a component updates that value, the others need to receive the updated value?

Comment: Yes, I would like the value to be shared between all components that access it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need that every component access the same reference to the same value, then you need to use a [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

If you want to see some examples, here some links:

- [Official React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#examples)
- [Kentcdodds example](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively)

Comment: From what I can tell, values are changed directly, not by setting the new state of a constant, and then calling a rerender to obtain the new value. Is this true? How does react context effect the render cycle of the app?

Comment: @figbar a react context is essentially a container for a value that can be everything (object etc..). Every time the value inside the context changes, every component subscribed to that context are notified and, therefore, re-rendered. Of course this is a very basic explanation, if you read the links posted in the answer you'll understand better.

Comment: Ok I am attempting to use Context, but am having some issues changing the stored value. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68583648/react-native-context-not-updating-across-files-and-screens. Any chance you could assist?

Comment: @figbar there is an answer to that question and I think is correct. You need to wrap all the components that need to access the context, so you have to move up the Provider in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You would write a custom hook for sharing logic between functional components

```js
export default function useMyHook() {
   const [test, setTest] = React.useState(0);

   const _hookfunction = function(){
       setTest(1);
       return true;
   };

   // Then you can return anything you want
   return [test, _hookfunction];
}
```

And in your component

```js
export default function HookTest() {
   const [test, setTest] = useMyHook();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify that I want all of the components that access it to share and be able to change the same value